# Import / create a Wallet from a key with bitcoind or bitcoin-cli to use as a hotwallet?

Tags: bitcoind, private-key

i've created a HD Wallet via (https://github.com/GemHQ/money-tree)

i would like to take the private key and throw that into my daemon so i can listen on incoming transactions and also transfer the funds to our coldwallet via RPC calls.

how do i create a wallet.dat via privatekey only so that my daemon can open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `importprivkey` and `importmulti` RPC calls in `bitcoin-cli` to do this.

Comment: i figured out, it's more secure to not import the privatekey. just generate the adresses and put them on watchonly, so the wallet is just monitoring incoming transactions